# Does an odd degree map on $S^n$ descend to an odd degree maps on $\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

Suppose there is a map $f:S^n\to S^n$ that induces non-trivial on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ homology group homomorphisms, further suppose $f$ descends to $f':\mathbb{R}P^n\to\mathbb{R}P^n$. Does it then follows that $f$ induces nontrivial map of $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{Z}/2)$?

How do I see this best?

Comment: @JustinYoung This is what I am trying to see actually, but why?

Comment: Ok, my previous comments were wrong, the quotient map induces the zero map on $H_n$. But, if you take the associated homotopy cofiber sequence, you can obtain the result knowing the algebraic structure of the homology/cohomology of $\mathbb RP^n$.